# How do you incrementally increase values in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array populated with the same value, however, I want this value to incrementally decrease by a value of 0.025 with each row. It currently looks like this:

```
import numpy as np

vp_ref = 30
surf_lay = np.ones(([1000,10000]), dtype=np.float32);
gvp_ref = vp_ref * surf_lay
```

So the array is filled with 30s. I want the first row to be 30, decrease to 29.975 in the next row, and keep going until the bottom. How would I do this?

Comment: Can you explain why you need such an array? You might be facing an XY problem.

Comment: Better to say 'numpy' not Python, since you're using np.array. (Python has [arrays](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) too, but they're completely different and they suck).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution:

1. Define `step_range` to get all the values starting from 0, adding `step` until the end of your matrix size.
2. Subtract it!

```
step = 0.025
step_range = np.arange(0, gvp_ref.shape[0] * step, step).reshape(-1, 1)
print(gvp_ref - step_range)
```

Output:

```
array([[30.   , 30.   , 30.   , ..., 30.   , 30.   , 30.   ],
       [29.975, 29.975, 29.975, ..., 29.975, 29.975, 29.975],
       [29.95 , 29.95 , 29.95 , ..., 29.95 , 29.95 , 29.95 ],
       ...,
       [ 5.075,  5.075,  5.075, ...,  5.075,  5.075,  5.075],
       [ 5.05 ,  5.05 ,  5.05 , ...,  5.05 ,  5.05 ,  5.05 ],
       [ 5.025,  5.025,  5.025, ...,  5.025,  5.025,  5.025]])
```

Comment: Calling `np.full` broadcasting is a bit of a stretch. You could use `np.broadcast_to` and then it would be true. Actually, I'm pretty sure broadcasting would work as `gvp_ref - step_range`...

Comment: I thought `gvp_ref - step_range` would work but it didn't initially. In fact, with `.reshape(1000,1)`, you're right, it does! Thanks @AndrasDeak, edited, that's cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.linspace` for creating the linearly spaced data and then `np.tile` for creating the 2D array:

```
n = 1000
tmp = np.linspace(30, 30 - (n-1)*0.025, n)
result = np.tile(tmp[:, None], (1, 10_000))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, in this code alpha is 0.025

```
import numpy as np
vp_ref = 30
surf_lay = np.ones(([1000,10000]), dtype=np.float32);
gvp_ref = vp_ref * surf_lay

alpha = 0.025
substration_array = np.array([[alpha*i]*gvp_ref.shape[1] for i in range(gvp_ref.shape[0])])

gvp_ref.shape
substration_array.shape

output = np.subtract(gvp_ref, substration_array)
```